# Why am I getting this error when loading my TableViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm working on a project for iOS5 using ARC and storyboard.

I have a mapview with annotations with a disclosure button going to my DetailView (which is a TableViewController) but when it's supposed to be loaded, I get the following error:

```
2012-07-18 14:09:43.328 Zone-It-new[1966:707] Loadded the view for MapViewController
2012-07-18 14:11:40.467 Zone-It-new[1966:707] -[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x138470
2012-07-18 14:11:40.470 Zone-It-new[1966:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x138470'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3748488f 0x35189259 0x37487a9b 0x37486915 0x373e1650 0x311997ef 0x31195059 0x31194711 0x3119466b 0x311945e7 0x31284f63 0x311979bb 0x311973ad 0x31191b8b 0x311917d5 0x9386d 0x3120a93d 0x31284627 0x37cf5933 0x37458a33 0x37458699 0x3745726f 0x373da4a5 0x373da36d 0x33b99439 0x31186cd5 0x924b3 0x92458)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

This is my detailviewcontroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Event.h"

@interface DetailViewController :  UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
     IBOutlet UILabel *title;
     IBOutlet UILabel *description;
     IBOutlet UILabel *zone;
     IBOutlet UILabel *gemeente;
     IBOutlet UILabel *plaats;
     IBOutlet UILabel *deelnemers;
     IBOutlet UILabel *start;
     IBOutlet UILabel *einde;
     IBOutlet UILabel *id_nr;
}

@property (nonatomic) Event *event;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title, *zone, *description, *gemeente, *deelnemers, *start, *einde, *plaats, *id_nr;
@end
```

part of the DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];


    /*title.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;*/
    [title lineBreakMode];
    [title setText:[event title]];
    [title sizeToFit];

    gemeente.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [title lineBreakMode];
    [gemeente setText:[event gemeente]];
}
```

And this is where the view gets created in via the ListView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    SingletonManager *sharedManager = [SingletonManager sharedManager];

    [detail setEvent:[sharedManager.eventsManager objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Event.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Event : NSObject <MKAnnotation>


// required property from mkanotation
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

// Optional
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *zone;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *gemeente;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *straat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int deelnemers;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *start;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *einde;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *plaats;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int id_nr;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int huisnummer;



@end
```

----- Some more debugging information -------

While using the exception breakpoints it stopped here:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

console:

```
2012-07-18 15:53:46.691 Zone-It-new[179:707] Loadded the view for MapViewController 
2012-07-18 15:54:01.940 Zone-It-new[179:707] -[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170bb0 
(lldb)
```

Comment: If the disclosure button calls the Detail, what do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];` does in `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
`?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with your exception but `[title lineBreakMode];` isn't going to change anything.  It's just a property reference that returns the current mode (which you don't use).

Comment: Did use some breakpoints to see where your crash is happening ?

Comment: @NatanR. This exceprt of code you are refering to is from my listview, and not the mapview and that function is the function that is called when a listitem is selected, the mapview has something different.

Comment: @Pierre I did use some breakpoints it gets all the way till till the last line of didSelectRow etc etc and even in the viewDidLoad but in the console (lldb) appears sooner, don't know if that points out an error?

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for pointing that 'dead code' out ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is to rename the `title` property in the `UIViewController`. This is due to the fact that `UIViewController` already defines an `NSString *` property with a name of `title`.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that somewhere in your code you're trying to copy a UILabel.  UIView subclasses don't adhere to the `NSCopying` protocol, so trying to copy any UIView will result in an exception (unless it's a subclass that does implements the protocol).  I'd search through your code base to check where the copy is occurring.  If you can't find any place that explicitly copies the UILabel, check collection classes.  Some collections classes will copy values in (NSDictionary does this with keys, so if you're trying to use a UILabel as a key for a NSDictionary, you'll get the error).  Also check your properties.  What you show in your displayed code is fine, but if you specify a `copy` in a protocol for a UILabel, that'll also give the error.

You should also try standard debugging techniques like setting a breakpoint for all exceptions.  (go to the breakpoints nav pane, at the bottom click the plus sign).  This should help you find the problem by breaking on your offending line of code.  Just be aware that if the copying is occurring in Apple's code (like setting a NSDictionary key) the breakpoint might not break on your code.

**Update**

Given your new code, I would suggest trying the following:

1. Try to find any place in your code where "anything" is copied.  Obviously your not explicitly copying UILabel but maybe you're accidentally copying it by passing the wrong argument somewhere.  For example: Remove all `copy` keywords from your Event properties and test it again.  You probably don't need to specify `copy` for NSString anyway, but what we're doing here is making sure you're not accidentally setting a UILabel to one of those properties.  If the code doesn't break, you didn't fix it but now you know what the problem is (trying to assign a UILabel to the wrong property).
2. Start commenting out various blocks of code, one at a time, to find the problem.  For example, comment out your entire `viewDidLoad` method and test your code.  If it works, you know the problem is in there.  So uncomment part of the method and test again.  Keep repeating until you've narrowed down the problem.  If it still breaks with `viewDidLoad`, uncomment that and try a different block of code.  In essence, you're playing detective to try to find the offending line of code.

Comment: I don't really know how to debug more? I debugged till the point of the end of the ViewDidLoad of the detailview.. But I can't break further? (and I didn't really find the debugging 'options' =/

Comment: I used the exceptions brekapoint, and got 'more' usefule information (perhaps) could you please check it?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would break on `pushViewController`.  That method will trigger a lot of activity in your view controller, like `viewDidLoad` for example, but if the problem were there, it should have broken inside the `viewDidLoad`.  I would suspect something is wired up wrong with IB.  I will add some debug suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can often mean you're trying to assign an object to a method that can't handle it, rather than a property of that object. For example, trying to set a UILabel to an object rather than a string property on that object.

My guess is it's this line:  `[gemeente setText:[event gemeente]];`

There could also be an issue here:

```
@property (nonatomic) Event *event;
```

You haven't set `Event *event` as an instance variable but are referencing it as one. Try `self.event` for accessing event as you have it above.

Comment: I added my event.h file, as you can see [event gemeente] returns a string, right?

Comment: I updated my answer, I'm not sure you're accessing event properly.

Comment: That did not work, I added some 'debugging' info, it's not much but I don't know how to debug it 'further' into the project

Comment: change your synthesize declaration to @synthesize event = _event and retry with self.event